# Unable to create new netbeans 8.2 projects on MacOS version Mojave 10.14.1

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, macos-mojave

I am unable to create new netbeans projects on MacOS Mojave 10.14.1.  When I choose File>New Project...   --->> no dialog box opens and the IDE log is the following:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@27506e4f[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@4994c66[org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@36d4b5c, ModuleCL@364f78b6[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...<snip>...
    java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Ok, so here are some details so that I can post the question.  I used homebrew to install the netbeans IDE.  It did not give any errors.  I am able to open an existing project (a dialog box does open for that).

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 will not work with any JDK > 8, so... [1] How many versions of Java are installed on your machine? [2] What version of Java is NetBeans actually using? (**Help > About** and **Tools > Java Platforms**).

Comment: I had the wrong version of JDK installed ... so I tried to uninstall it:  Ralfs-$ javac -version
javac 11.0.1
$ brew cask uninstall java
Then I installed the "correct version" brew tap caskroom/versions .... brew cask install java8 and set the $JAVA_HOME to the location of the jdk1.8.0_192. netbeans is using something else ... Java; VM; Vendor        = 11.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.1+13-LTS; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 11.0.1+13-LTS
  Java Home               = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: After installing jdk1.8.0_192, the solution was to then edit the netbeans.conf file to set netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @skomisa for pointing out the problem.

1. I had the "wrong" version of JDK installed -- version 11.0.1 and netbeans was configured by default to use it.
2. I then installed what appears to be the latest "correct version": 
   $ brew tap caskroom/versions
   $ brew cask install java8 (jdk1.8.0_192).
3. After installing jdk1.8.0_192, then edit the /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf file to set netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home"
4. Start netbeans and you are ready to go!